# Чи є відповідник до слова "тренінг"?

Tags: іменники, запозичені-слова

Часто практикують у школах уроки з елементами ***тренінгів***, а також і в практичній психології цей тип заняття доволі популярний. Отож цікавить, *чи є український відповідник до цього слова?* Адже у тому ж [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/treningh) знаходимо лише такі значення:

> **ТРЕ́НІНГ**, у, чол.
>
> 1. Тренування, а також спеціальний тренувальний режим
> 2. Спеціальне приміщення для тренування (у 1 знач.).

На інших сайтах, чомусь, не знайшла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/treninh) знаходимо такі відповідники:

> **вишкіл,
>   майстерка,
>   вдосконалення**.

У [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3):

> ТРЕНУВА́ННЯ, ТРЕНА́Ж, ТРЕ́НІНГ